# Entity Framework: AsNoTracking for included child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I use `AsNoTracking` on the top-level entity, does it get applied to all the child entities?

So for example, if I write like this

```
context.FirstEntity.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(f => f.ChildEntity_1)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.ChildEntity_1_1)
    .Include(f => f.ChildEntitiy_2);
```

Will the `AsNoTracking` be applied to all the child entities automatically since it is applied to the top-level entity?

Or I have to call the function separately for all the child entities too? like this

```
context.FirstEntity.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(f => f.ChildEntity_1).AsNoTracking()
    .ThenInclude(c => c.ChildEntity_1_1).AsNoTracking()
    .Include(f => f.ChildEntitiy_2).AsNoTracking();
```

Comment: Turn it to an IQueryable then the collections will be available with Include

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AsNoTracking` causes the *entire query* to not be tracked. This includes any child entities that might be returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried a similar case (please don't critique this - it's not my code!) and you can't place .AsNoTracking() on a .Include() followed by a .ThenInclude() call because it causes a compile-time error:

```
return _context.Feedback
        .Include(x => x.Property).AsNoTracking() // Causes a compile error
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Owner).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Booking)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.BookingTravellers).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Contact).AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1061  'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no accessible extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The compiler is happy with:

```
    return _context.Feedbacks
        .Include(x => x.Property)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Owner).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Booking)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.BookingTravellers).AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Contact).AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```